# package is not in GOROOT

Tags: go

I'm making some mini project with golang. I defined global variable and make it as a separated package. so, my directory status like below. but when I import this in 'image.go'it says 'package comento/works/internal/global is not in GOROOT'. Additionary, global's variables in image.go works well.but jsut import occures error. I also made go.mod file and tried to command 'go mod tidy' either.  How can I resolve this?

directory tree
(/usr/local/go/src/comento/works/internal/global)

```
works
.
├── README.md
├── file
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── index
│   └── index.html
├── internal
│   └── global.go
├── main.go
└── pkg
    ├── api
    │   └── image.go
    └── router
        └── router.go
```

image.go

```
import "comento/works/internal/global".
```

go.mod

```
module comento/works

go 1.19

require github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.2
```

Comment: You cannot import files. Go only allows the importing of packages. Also "internal" is a special directory in Go and you should generally not use it as a package but you can use it as a directory under which other packages live. Create a directory `works/internal/global` and move `global.go` into there. Change the package clause of the `global.go` file to be `package global`. In `image.go` import as `"comento/works/internal/global"` and use the variables as `global.Foo`, `global.Bar`, etc.

Comment: For more details about internal directories, see: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Internal_Directories